# how to update textarea value in php ajax with ckeditor?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am using CkEditor in my website.

when i am updating data in database using php ajax in textarea field but data is not showing textarea field. But without ckeditor my code is running perfectly. please help me !!

Comment: can you show your related code

Comment: please add your code that you tried

Comment: <textarea name="desc" id="desc" class="form-control ckeditor" rows="15" cols="65"></textarea>

Comment: $(document).on('click', '.update', function(){
   var user_id = $(this).attr("id");
   var action = "Fetch Single Data";
   $.ajax({
    url:"action.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{user_id:user_id, action:action},
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(data)
    {
     $('.collapse').collapse("show");
  
     $('#desc').val(data.desc);
     $('#uploaded_image').html(data.image);
     $('#hidden_user_image').val(data.user_image);
     $('#button_action').val("Edit");
     $('#action').val("Edit");
     $('#user_id').val(user_id);
    }
   });
  });

Comment: ck editor data you need to save i a hidden text and use this text to save data

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `CkEditor` set data method [documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#setData)

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData(data.desc);
```

Comment: where to used CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData(data.desc); code

Comment: replace this line   $('#desc').val(data.desc);  with this line CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData(data.desc); @sam

Comment: if my answer is useful mark it with green tick it's useful for future user reference . @sam

Comment: But i have another problem ...when i submit data ...data saved on  submit second time in database not first time.

Comment: i think it seems new issue . so you can make new post with detail . so people will help you and i too @sam

Answer (score -1):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "function/fetch.php",
    dataType: "html",
    data: {updateEmailTemplateID: id,UserID:UserID },
    success: function (response) { 
        response = JSON.parse(response);
        $('input[name="Updatetitle"]').val(response.title);
        CKEDITOR.instances.editor2.setData(response.description);
        $('#Update').modal('show');
    }
});
```